# How to know a specific url image is already downloaded with using SDWebImage library?

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

I have a lot of group images displaying for user to download optional. What I wanna do is that if user already download it, my UILabel should show "already downloaded", and "download" if user didn't download yet.

I use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), so how to know a specific url image is already downloaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import

```
#import <SDWebImageManager.h>
```

Then

```
BOOL isCached =  [[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] diskImageExistsForURL:imageURL];
```